# PHP Error log in CP gives me 403 forbidden

Tags: error-message

If I want to view the PHP Error logs from craft true utils/logs I get an 403 Forbidden error.

nginx/1.6.2

../admin/utils/logs/phperrors.log

What could be wrong?

Comment: You can view the `craft.log`, `craft.log.1`, etc. files fine? Is it an nginx 403 or a Craft one?

Comment: craft.log works. and yes it is an nginx error.

Comment: Sounds like some weird nginx configuration/permissions issue. Strange.

Answer (score 4):

Had the same problem. I my case, it was the following code in my nginx config file:

```
location ~* (?:\.(?:bak|config|sql|fla|ini|log|sh|inc|swp|dist)|~)$ {
    deny all;
}
```

After removing **log|** from the list, the problem was solved.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a file permission issue. Make sure that `phperrors.log` has acceptable read permissions.

Comment: Not working. Read permissions are the same as craft.log. And they work normal. 

Tried other permission settings. Same error.

Comment: I also have this issue, all the files in /craft/storage/runtime/logs are: `-rw-r--r--  1 forge forge` - I can access `/admin/utils/logs` but if I select another logfile, I get the same nginx 403.